# Merge Pull Request - How do I know what It's merging Into?

Tags: git, github

So shamefully this is the first time doing a merge on a PR.  I'm actually trying to test my build script, specifically test that I'm getting a value for TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH.  I have to do a PR to do that.  But what I'd also like to do is to undo the PR, and keep redoing it like that so I can keep testing my new script that way...causing the script to run every time I PR it again.

Well to be able to revert a PR, you have to merge your PR.  We have a master branch and then a `development` branch.  The development branch is set to be the default branch.

I don't want to click the merge pull request quite yet, I'm afraid if I do, it might merge to the default branch but I'm not quite sure.

How do I know or how can I figure out which branch this PR branch will try to merge into if I click that?

Comment: `Well to be able to revert a PR, you have to merge your PR.` Do you need to merge and revert? Could you delete the PR and remake it fresh for the next run? You're probably better off merging and resetting to eliminate the merge (or just reset the whole repo) than filling the repo with revert commits. Maybe you should ask about your testing setup, there's probably a better way to do it. ...you are doing this on a test repo for this project, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of the pull request it will have two branches indicated in `text formatted like this`. See the below image.

[image]

The branch on on the left is the 'destination', as indicated by the text 'wants to merge 1 commit into' (destination). The branch on the right (merging branch) is the branch being merged onto the left branch.

Comment: if I want to keep retesting a PR on a branch without doing a merge yet, with the goal of testing out a new travis build script, is there an easy way to do that?  I don't want to have to keep manually creating a new branch, PR'ing it just to get my script to kick off on that PR branch

Comment: You can just continue committing to the branch you have created - Travis will re-run the build for these commits.

Comment: This comment thread has been moved to [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525859/best-way-to-test-travis-pull-request)

Comment: @PositiveGuy if this question has been resolved, it is recommended to mark the most appropriate answer as the accepted solution.